# Java AudioInputStream IOException cannot read a single byte if frame size > 1

Tags: java, audio, audio-streaming, java-io, ioexception

So I'm making a Java game program, and I'm adding music to it right now. However, when I used AudioInputStream, it didn't work on my program.

```
    public static void playMusic(String filepath) {
    InputStream music;
    try {
        music = new AudioStream(new FileInputStream(filepath));            
        AudioStream audios = new AudioStream(music);           
        AudioPlayer.player.start(audios);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error:" + e.toString());
    }
}
```

The result was the Error: java.io.IOException: cannot read a single byte if frame size > 1. I then opened a new program, and it works perfectly fine.

```
    public class PlayMusic {

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String args[]){
        playMusic("Mars.wav");
    }

    public static void playMusic(String filepath) {
        InputStream music;

    try{
    music = new FileInputStream(new File(filepath));
    AudioStream audios = new AudioStream(music);
    AudioPlayer.player.start(audios);
    } catch(IOException e){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Error");    
    }
    }
```

}

I looked at some other places, but they had no information for my case. I have multiple classes all connected to my Main class. When I run the project, it runs from the main.

Edit:
I just moved the code to the bottom of the main method, and now it works. However, I'm still curious as to why this fixed it.

Comment: It seems really old program. Are you coming from 1997 because it seemingly use the _sun.audio package_? Am I right?

Comment: Don't use `sun.audio.AudioPlayer` it has been removed in Java 9 and later releases.

Comment: @greg-449 humm, I was unaware of its removal process, thanks for the information

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm writing the answer to solve your problem, not to point to the issue, however, a while ago I read that is a bug in `AudioStream`.

If it is a dummy sound, there is no need to make an effort too much, take the advantages of JavaFx and Java 8.

```
static {
    JFXPanel fxPanel = new JFXPanel();
}

private static void playSound(String sound){
    // cl is the ClassLoader for the current class, ie. CurrentClass.class.getClassLoader();
    URL file = cl.getResource(sound);
    final Media media = new Media(file.toString());
    final MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer(media);
    mediaPlayer.play();
}
```